# How to get access token by an API created using apigee I java

Tags: java, api, http-post, http-status-code-401

API request works fine in postman but I am not able to the same in Java. Here are some pictures of post man and code

https://ibb.co/mA8VRK https://ibb.co/eJLife https://ibb.co/bxen6K https://ibb.co/bR5S6K https://ibb.co/bR5S6K https://ibb.co/e2J8Dz

I am getting 401 (Unauthorized) response when I run the java code.

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not able to the same in Java"? Please add the error that you are seeing.

Comment: i am getting 401(unauthorised) as response

Comment: First thing is, you are using `https` in your java code while you used `http` in your postman request. Also, you would need to pass the Authorization in your header just like you did in postman.

Comment: Post your java code in your question instead of only the image.